# Best practises for storing records with formatting errors which don't fit column data type

Tags: database-design

Our platform allows the user to import records from CSV files.

In case there are errors, the user has the ability to fix them in the web portal where we fill a form with the wrong values uploaded by the user along with a friendly error message.

Due to regulation, our columns have strict acceptable data type, range, character-set, etc.

Some of the common mistakes is the precision, e.g customer provides a double with 20 digits where it's acceptable to have 10, or country name should be 3 letter ISO country code and they provide full name.

We are using MariaDB and so far we were storing records with formatting errors in a separate table which has a column with TEXT data type and record data in JSON, which allows us to easily serialise/deserialise and send the record data over our API.

This has been working fine for small users or with few errors. However over time we have users with several thousands of such errors on a daily basis which make the processing take for ever after few weeks and also taking up a lot of storage (a record has ~200 columns).

Any recommendations on which design to follow or whether a different technology should be used?

Comment: Why not present them the errors and force them to immediately correct them on the app side before saving the input to the database?

Comment: @J.D. We thought about it and it’s a good fit when adding a single record on the app but due to the number of records we have to offer a CSV import mechanism which is over SFTP. The main reason we want to keep the error values is to provide better UX because we have multiple columns and it wouldn’t be easy for the user to read e.g a report/feedback file with the errors of the ingestion.